# How to make FOS User Bundle login user after email verification?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

After entering login details FOS User Bundle sends confirmation email. Link in letter just make account active but not force it to login. How can I force FOSUB to login user on email verification?

Comment: what about redirect him to the login path after activation ?
did you override your fos controllers ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create an eventListener 
with implementation of :

```
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
```

after , you need to create class to work with

```
class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
```

and override some method specialy

```
 public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $url = 'use your route to generate the url if you wanna redirect him to login area after cofirm or confimed ' ;

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
```

**NB: be careful about the difference between confirm and confirmed**

and you last step to specify a on your yml service a route to use on the $url variable 
but you can use any protected route on your security.yml (specialy the main path if he is protected ) that will bring him straight to login area .

Comment: Thanks! It really helps. After redirect I use code for login:
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
        $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
        $this->container->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        $this->container->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);